# How to get the on-screen width of the prompt produced by PS1 (with or without @P)?

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors, prompt

Suppose, for example, that `PS1` has the value shown below:

```
'\w (\[\e[32m\]${__git_ps1_branch_name}\[\e[0m\] \[\e[31m\]*\[\e[31m\]%\[\e[0m\]>)\$ '
```

...where `__git_ps1_branch_name` is some string, like `master` or `feature123`.

**Q:** I am looking for a way to compute the on-screen width (in number of characters) of the prompt that `bash` will generate from a `PS1` like the one shown above.

---

Recent versions of `bash` expand the expression `${PS1@P}` to the string obtained by replacing the elements of the prompt specification above by their final display values.  (Thus `\w` will be replaced by the path to the current directory, for example, and `${__git_ps1_branch_name}` will be replaced by the string contained in the `__git_ps1_branch_name` variable, etc.)  This however is not enough to solve the problem.

More specifically, if we set:

```
EXPANDED_PS1="${PS1@P}"
```

...the expression `${#EXPANDED_PS1}` (i.e. the number of characters in `$EXPANDED_PS1`) yields a number that is *significantly greater* than the on-screen width of the prompt that bash would generate from `$PS1`.  The excess comes from the escape sequences that confer color to the displayed prompt.

In any case, *I am **also** interested in solutions that will work with versions of bash that do not support `@P`*.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/how-to-expand-ps1

Answer (score 1):

Without support for `@P` it is difficult. The thing is, you need to expand PS1, but that function is private, so you cannot use it directly. Still, there are some very nice tries in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451993/how-to-expand-ps1).

If you do have support for `@P` then this might work for you:

```
$ echo -ne "\n${PS1@P}\033[6n";read -e -s -d R cnt;cnt=$((${cnt#;} - 1));echo $cnt
```

First a new line and the expanded `PS1` string are sent. That means that the cursor will now be at the column *length_of_PS1 + 1*.

Then the ANSI escape code *Device Status Report* (CSI6n) is sent. The terminal answers back with:

> Reports the cursor position (CPR) by transmitting ESC[n;mR, where n is the row and m is the column.)

The value is read from the standard input and placed into `cnt`.

It' hackish, just for ANSI terminals, but it seems to work. Note that if the expansion is longer than the width of the terminal, the column will not show the length of `PS1`. Output from other processes could also be a problem.